# Casting items of a collection with code generation

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit, il

I'm doing code generation with C# and I would like to cast a backing field inside a getter.

Here is an example:

```
public class Potato
{
}

public class ProxyPotato : Potato
{    
}

public class Stew
{
  private ICollection<ProxyPotato> _proxyPotatoes;

  //This is the code I would like to generate (specialy the cast part)
  public ICollection<Potato> Potatoes { get { return _proxyPotatoes.Cast<Potato>().ToList(); } }
}
```

I have this code which can generate a property but I don't know how to execute a Cast:

```
private static void SetProperty(TypeBuilder builder, string propertyName, Type propertyType, FieldBuilder fieldBuilder)
{
  const string GetterPrefix = "get_";
  const string SetterPrefix = "set_";

  // Generate the property
  var propertyBuilder = builder.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);


  // Property getter and setter attributes.
  const MethodAttributes propertyMethodAttributes = MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.Virtual;

  // Define the getter method.
  var getterMethod = builder.DefineMethod(string.Concat(GetterPrefix, propertyName), propertyMethodAttributes, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);

  // Emit the IL code.
  // ldarg.0
  // ldfld,_field
  // ret
  ILGenerator getterILCode = getterMethod.GetILGenerator();
  getterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
  getterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
  getterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

  // Define the setter method.
  MethodBuilder setterMethod = builder.DefineMethod(
  string.Concat(SetterPrefix, propertyName),
  propertyMethodAttributes, null, new Type[] { propertyType });

  // Emit the IL code.
  // ldarg.0
  // ldarg.1
  // stfld,_field
  // ret
  ILGenerator setterILCode = setterMethod.GetILGenerator();
  setterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
  setterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
  setterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);
  setterILCode.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

  propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getterMethod);
  propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setterMethod);
}
```

Comment: That's not casting. It's just a call to the static [Enumerable.Cast<T> Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx).

Comment: i'm just curious, what is the context your actually working in? I've never had to do anything like this and would like to know when it comes into play.

Comment: @dtb You are right! I will rename the question to: How to use OpCodes.Call to emit the equivalent of Cast<T>()

Comment: I created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104085/how-to-use-opcodes-call-to-generate-this-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cast extension method is a method call. You need to emit the following:

```
return Enumerable.ToList<Potato>(Enumerable.Cast<Potato>(_proxyPotatoes));
```

You can call these static methods using the OpCodes.Call instruction.

Comment: Right, and keep in mind that that's `Enumerable.ToList<Potato>(Enumerable.Cast<Potato>(_proxyPotatoes));`: the compiler will normally automatically supply the generic argument here, but if you're doing it manually, you need to specify it.

Comment: @hvd I edited this in. I forgot because I never write it that way ;-)

Comment: You are right! I will rename the question to: How to use OpCodes.Call to emit return Enumerable.ToList(Enumerable.Cast<Potato>(_proxyPotatoes)); Sorry but I am a newbie with code generation!

Comment: I created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104085/how-to-use-opcodes-call-to-generate-this-code